# Find $\beta \overline{\beta}$ for $\beta \equiv 1 \mod \sqrt{-7}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, theta-functions

Do I have this equivalence?
$$ \sum_{\beta \equiv 1 \mod \sqrt{-7}} \mathrm{Re}(\beta) e^{\beta \overline{\beta}/7} \stackrel{?}{=} \sum_{m, n }  m e^{m^2 + 7 n^2}$$

Let $\beta \in \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-7}}{2}]$ be the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7}) = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 + 7)$. 
$$ \beta \equiv 1 \mod \sqrt{-7}$$
If I let $\beta = m \cdot 1 + n \cdot \frac{1 + \sqrt{-7}}{2} $ what does this condition  mean in terms of $m, n, \in \mathbb{Z}$ ? The actual theta function equation should be something quite normal looking.